# .sln file went missing after Visual Studio crashed

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to setup a github repository in visual studio, I was messing with the branches in team explorer. I changed the branch from my current one to master, when Visual Studio crashed. I try to open the project again and visual studio tells me its missing...I go into the project root folder and no .sln file is there, only an .SUO file can be found.

I try to create a blank project and try to add an existing project with the .csproj file, but visual studio does not see the .csproj file even though there is one in the root folder of the project. Upon inspecting the .csproj file, it says its an Visual Studio Project User Options file (.user).

Previously I did manage to create a local git repository on my machine...
Please help, How can I retrieve my solution?

Thanks

Comment: You said that the sln file disappeared when you switch from a branch to another. So you should have your git repository already initialized and something committed inside. 
That should mean that if your sln is missing, that should be detected as a change by git and you must be able to reset them...

Comment: I do have a local .git repository in the project folder. It consists of directories such as "Hooks", "info", "logs", "objects", "refs". I am really new to git, and Im unsure how to get my files from there...

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get my original branch by pushing the master branch to GitHub. In GitHub I saw two branches (Master and my previous one). Previous one had all my files!

Unsure if this qualifies as an answer or not, or should I delete the post?