# Why is GitHub sometimes ignoring my Visual Studio files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, github

I'm using two computers with **Visual Studio Ultimate 2012** and the [**Github extension** for it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.VisualStudioToolsforGit).
There are **multiple solutions** in the repository.
**Sometimes after commiting**, the **sln**, **csproj**, **App.config** and **AssemblyInfo.cs** files are missing in the repository.

I found them with the Git Gui program under "**Unstaged Changes**" and could add them.
I have to do this **every time** I add a **new solution.**

As far as I can see it, the **.gitignore** file is **not responsible** for this.

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets
!packages/*/build/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml

# NuGet Packages Directory
## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment the next line
#packages/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf


#LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml

# =========================
# Windows detritus
# =========================

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac desktop service store files
.DS_Store
```

**What is the reason for this behaviour** and **how can it be fixed?**

**Edit for additional information:**

I'm only working on the **master**, there are **no branches**.

I tried it again. 
Files **untracked** were:

```
$ git status -u 
On branch master 
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.  
Untracked files:  
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)  

007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime.sln  
007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime.csproj  
007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/App.config  
007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/Properties /AssemblyInfo.cs
```

The files **ignored** were:

```
$ git status --ignored
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime.sln
        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime.csproj
        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/App.config
        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/Properties/

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        005 Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple.v11.suo
        005 Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple/bin/
        005 Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple/Smallest multiple/obj/
        006 Sum square difference/Sum square difference/Sum square difference.v11.suo
        006 Sum square difference/Sum square difference/Sum square difference/bin/
        006 Sum square difference/Sum square difference/Sum square difference/obj/
        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime.v11.suo
        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/bin/
        007 10001st prime/10001st prime/10001st prime/obj/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

It seems that they are **not ignored**, just **untracked**.

Comment: That might be a bug from ligbit2 used in VC2012, while VC2015 has shifted to git (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40059664/6309)

Answer (score 3):

To really be sure those files are not ignored, double-check (when you see that case again) with

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/missing/file.sln
```

That way, you will be sure no `.gitignore` is responsible.

Make sure you did not just switch from branches ([as in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956982/6309))

---

[Guy Lowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748133/guy-lowe) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294015/why-is-github-sometimes-ignoring-my-visual-studio-files/41295900#comment112020211_41295900):

> I had this issue with new `.cs` files with the line `*.user` in my gitignore
>
> It was because I had the word `user` in my **folder structure**.

Comment: Thanks.:) I'll try it when it happens again and update it. I have no branches. I only work on the master branch.

Comment: Yes, I had seen your previous edit, hence my comment.

Comment: I had this issue with new .cs files with the line *.user in my gitignore. Not sure why.

Comment: @GuyLowe Strange. Do you mean `git check-ignore -v` mention a `*.user` ignore rule for `.cs` files?

Comment: It was because I had the word user in my folder structure. I can't be the only one to have seen this but obviously the only one to mention it on SO.

Comment: @GuyLowe Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.